# Invalid Mail Nickname

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to add a user to my B2C Tenant, and am getting an error stating that the `mail nickname` is invalid.

I created the `nickname` by concatenating the trimmed `firstname` and `lastname` without any included spaces.

I think the trouble might be that this user is Russian...

I can't find any definitive specification of what characters are allowed in this attribute.

Does anyone know of such a document, or how to overcome this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **mailNickname** property of the **user** object isn't used by Azure AD B2C so it is common to set this property value to "Unknown".

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2824766/mailnickname-or-alias-attribute-in-exchange-online-doesn-t-match-what

The Alias or Mailnickname attribute in Microsoft Exchange Online doesn't match what is set in the Exchange on-premises environment for a synced user account.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a synced account, just a new user in the B2C.